# How to overwrite a specific column in a text file?

Tags: python

I am new to python and I have a text file which I wanted to append. I have a set of variables which I want to append in a text file. For example I have the following variables:

```
pressure=25000
Mach=0.9
```

Suppose my first line in my text file which I intend to edit is as follows:

```
0.85 and 23908
```

So, here my Mach=0.85 and pressure=23908. How do I tell python to overwrite the value of Mach=0.9 for 0.85 and pressure=25000 for 23908? What is the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. You have two variables in python script and they have some default values (Mach = 0.9 and pressure=25000). You want to read the values from a text file and update your python variables?

Comment: In my text file I have the two numbers 0.85 and 23908. These values represent Mach and pressure respectively. All I want to do is change 0.85 with whatever value of my variable Mach. I also want to do this for pressure.

Comment: You want to use values of your variables and write the values in the file?

Comment: I already have a file which contains the variables. I just want to append it and write it to a new file and save this. So my new text file should contain 0.9 and 25000.

Comment: Have you tried something? It would be great if we can see your script or attempt even if it not working.

Comment: with open('Test.txt', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()
filedata = filedata.replace('0.85', 'Mf'). I have called Mach 'Mf'. But all it does is replacing 0.85 by Mf and not by the variable.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add expected OUTPUT and your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Python myself, so my answer might not be what you're looking for. You mention wanting to overwrite as well as append to a new file, so not entirely sure what output you expect, however, this is what I've come up with

```
pressure = 25000
Mach = 0.9

fileName = "text.txt"

originalText = ""
with open("otherfile.txt", "a+") as f2:
    with open(fileName, "r") as f:

        originalText = f.readlines()

    f2.write(str(originalText)[2:-2])
    f2.write("\n")    
    f2.write(str(Mach) + " and " + str(pressure) + "\n")
```

This code reads your current file that has the "0.85 and 23908" in it. Then it takes adds that to a new file, then lastly adds a new line with your updated variables. The output would be:

```
0.85 and 23908
0.9 and 25000
```

If you want to overwrite the contents of the new file every time your variables change, you would just change the "a+" to a "w".
If you want to look for the 0.85 and 23908 values in the text file I'd suggest using a dictionary.

Comment: This is what I wanted to achieve. Thank you for your valuable input.

Comment: What if I wanted to overwrite the first line? I don't want to add a new line.

Comment: @Mason If you only want 1 line of the most current values of Mach and pressure, then you would just remove the "f2.write(str(originalText)[2:-2])", and change the "a+" to a "w" in this line: "with open("otherfile.txt", "a+") as f2:"